# SQL query SUM syntax (classic ASP project)

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, asp-classic, sum

[image]

I have 3 tables: **MONTHS**, **STORES**, **REPORTS** (attached image sample).

I want to write a SQL query that will **SUM** the records (`day_amount`) from the table `REPORTS` but only the records having the same store and the same month.

I need something like that:

```
SELECT SUM(REPORTS.day_amount) AS GRAND_TOTAL
FROM REPORTS
WHERE MONTHS.month_id = REPORTS.month_id
  AND STORES.store_id = REPORTS.store_id
```

Is that correct? I have to use the GROUP BY?

Comment: Yes that is correct. You don't need grouping. Your query is fine.

Comment: You have not referenced the other tables in your SQL Statement. You may need to look up and perform JOIN statements here if you want to use them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure you're joining the other tables (if you need to do this).

```
SELECT 
     MONTHS.month_id
    ,STORES.store_id
    ,SUM(REPORTS.day_amount) AS GRAND_TOTAL
FROM REPORTS
INNER JOIN MONTHS ON MONTHS.month_id = REPORTS.month_id
INNER JOIN STORES ON STORES.store_id = REPORTS.store_id
GROUP BY MONTHS.month_id, STORES.store_id
```

Although, it doesn't appear you actually need the other tables at all, you could try something like this;

```
SELECT 
     REPORTS.month_id
    ,REPORTS.store_id
    ,SUM(REPORTS.day_amount) AS GRAND_TOTAL
FROM REPORTS
GROUP BY REPORTS.month_id, REPORTS.store_id
```